# Why is my gt Table only displaying 2 columns and every other row of data when my df is 3 columns?

Tags: r, gt

I have a df that has three columns: "Name", "Source", and "Average Disease Severity". I wanted to generate a simple table displaying this information. When I do so using the code below it only shows me a table with the "Source" and "Avg Disease Severity" columns. On top of this, in the numeric Avg column it is only showing the data for every other row? My df is character, characer, double. I added in the select and cols_label functions to try to force it to select all my columns but it is still not working. The Df is 38 rows in total.

Any reason why this is generating wrong?

Thank you,

My session info is:
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] kableExtra_1.4.0 knitr_1.42       sjPlot_2.8.15    ggpubr_0.6.0     dunn.test_1.3.5
[6] lubridate_1.9.2  forcats_1.0.0    stringr_1.5.0    dplyr_1.1.2      purrr_1.0.1
[11] readr_2.1.4      tidyr_1.3.0      tibble_3.2.1     ggplot2_3.4.2    tidyverse_2.0.0
[16] gtsummary_1.7.2  gt_0.10.1        readxl_1.4.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] nlme_3.1-160         fs_1.6.2             insight_0.19.7       bslib_0.4.2
[5] tools_4.2.2          backports_1.4.1      utf8_1.2.3           R6_2.5.1
[9] sjlabelled_1.2.0     colorspace_2.1-0     withr_2.5.0          tidyselect_1.2.0
[13] processx_3.8.1       emmeans_1.8.5        compiler_4.2.2       performance_0.10.8
[17] cli_3.6.1            xml2_1.3.4           labeling_0.4.2       bayestestR_0.13.1
[21] sass_0.4.5           scales_1.2.1         mvtnorm_1.1-3        systemfonts_1.0.4
[25] commonmark_1.9.0     digest_0.6.31        minqa_1.2.5          svglite_2.1.3
[29] rmarkdown_2.21       pkgconfig_2.0.3      htmltools_0.5.5      lme4_1.1-33
[33] highr_0.10           fastmap_1.1.1        rlang_1.1.0          rstudioapi_0.14
[37] jquerylib_0.1.4      farver_2.1.1         generics_0.1.3       jsonlite_1.8.4
[41] car_3.1-2            magrittr_2.0.3       Matrix_1.5-1         Rcpp_1.0.10
[45] munsell_0.5.0        fansi_1.0.4          abind_1.4-5          lifecycle_1.0.3
[49] stringi_1.7.12       carData_3.0-5        MASS_7.3-58.1        grid_4.2.2
[53] promises_1.2.0.1     sjmisc_2.8.9         lattice_0.20-45      ggeffects_1.3.4
[57] splines_4.2.2        chromote_0.2.0       sjstats_0.18.2       hms_1.1.3
[61] ps_1.7.5             pillar_1.9.0         boot_1.3-28          markdown_1.12
[65] estimability_1.4.1   ggsignif_0.6.4       glue_1.6.2           evaluate_0.20
[69] modelr_0.1.11        broom.helpers_1.14.0 vctrs_0.6.2          nloptr_2.0.3
[73] tzdb_0.3.0           cellranger_1.1.0     gtable_0.3.3         webshot2_0.1.1
[77] cachem_1.0.7         xfun_0.39            xtable_1.8-4         broom_1.0.4
[81] rstatix_0.7.2        later_1.3.0          viridisLite_0.4.1    websocket_1.4.1
[85] timechange_0.2.0

code is below.

```
> dput(head(Validation_Means_1))
structure(list(Name = c("Amelia", "Amethyst Improved", "Aroma 2", "Aromatto", "Aurelia", "Boxwood"), 
Source = c("NE Seed", "Johnny's Selected Seeds", "Johnny's Selected Seeds", "Hazzard's Seeds", "Renee's Garden", "Hazzard's Seeds"), 
`Average Disease Severity` = c(3.22, 3.75, 1.42, 4.5, 3.58, 4.42)), 
class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
groups = structure(list(
    Name = c("Amelia", "Amethyst Improved", "Aroma 2", "Aromatto", "Aurelia", "Boxwood"), 
.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .drop = TRUE))


Validation_Summary_Table <- Validation_Means_1 %>%
  select("Name", "Source", "Average Disease Severity"
         ) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Accession Information",
    columns = c("Name", "Source")
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    Name = "Name",
    Source = "Source",
    `Average Disease Severity`= "Average Disease Severity"
  ) 
print(Validation_Summary_Table)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or some fake data or using a built-in dataset. As is we can only speculate what's the issue as we can't run your code.

Comment: @Old_Man_Barrett To make this reproducible, would use `dput` instead of posting an image (as suggested above). Note the column names differ (in the image it is just "Average" not "Average Disease Severity"). I believe you will be more assistance with a more complete, reproducible example.

Comment: I believe I have added it properly now! Thank you both.

Comment: @Old_Man_Barrett Thanks - adding the data is helpful. Your data is "grouped" - add "ungroup" in your pipe before converting to `gt` table, and it should work.